# Can table in psql be named with 'references'

Tags: psql

I'm wondering can I rename a table to "references"? I want to name a table back to "references" but there is a syntax error. Is there anyway to fix it?

```
alter table referencesc rename to references;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "references"
LINE 1: alter table referencesc rename to references;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably being caused by that `references` is a [keyword in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).  To get around this, you can try escaping the table name in double quotes:

```
alter table referencesc rename to "references";
```

But in general you should avoid naming columns, tables, etc. using reserved keywords, because you will likely have to escape such names everywhere.

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much!!